# Save JSON data in string array, and then iterate over it in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Here I create english array, so I can use it in another function.

```
 var englsih = [];
$('#get_test').click(function() {
            $.post('ajax-request.php', {
                        act: 'start_test'
                    }, function(data) {

                        var jstring = $.parseJSON(data);

                        english = jstring.english_word;
```

Problem is to save in this array JSON data, and then use it in other places.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#quiz_form', function() {
     alert(englsih.length);
});
```

This alert shows me 0 length, though it should be 5 (MySql returns 5 objects).

Comment: You’re using both `englsih` and `english`. Another problem might be covered here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/4642212).

Comment: if you write  `console.log(englsih );` instance `alert(englsih .length);` what is your ouput?

Comment: @ashkufaraz I tried both, but I didn't get any alert, seems like it just ignored. I corrected code from 'englsih' to 'english'

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
english = jstring.english_word;
```

should be

```
englsih = jstring.english_word;
```

I think that you should check your code seriously